# select latest duplicate record from table got long process MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, optimization, duplicates

I have a query to only display one duplicate data and retrieve the one with latest date. But the process is very long. what kind of query should I write to be more efficient?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT d.id_qr, d.code_qr, d.date, d3.code id_code 
FROM survey d 
INNER JOIN place d3 on d.id_code = d3.id_code 
WHERE d.date IN (SELECT max(d2.date)FROM survey d2 WHERE d2.code_qr=d.code_qr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of aggregating, you could try `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. Also, you probably want an equality instead of `IN`.

```
SELECT d.id_qr, d.code_qr, d.date, d3.code id_code 
FROM survey d 
INNER JOIN place d3 on d.id_code = d3.id_code 
WHERE d.date = (
    SELECT d2.date 
    FROM survey d2 
    WHERE d2.code_qr = d.code_qr
    ORDER BY d2.date DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

For performance, consider an index on `survey(code_qr, date)`.

Comment: From 40 seconds to 0.1303 seconds -  thanks so much

Comment: Good to hear that! I was not expected that much benefit... Welcome @Xerror!